# Conditional typescript property type based on object value

Tags: typescript

Why typescript doesn't show errors and how to make it work?

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAgiCWECGAbKBvAsAKClAQgJIBKAIlALxQDkARvAE4Am1ANDnqQPIDilNTAPYBzNjgC+OHPBAAXYAwBmSAMbAoAZQiyAFgB4AKlGAAPeSCYBnWAmRoqcRKgB8GDlHhMAXFHARaCgDc7ki2qAYAngAOwD4GwbhQKoIgivDCccZmoFY09MzUUAD8vpABDFA+lrIMMsKBUAD0jR6KHrLW+UxQALRQljqCYCjdAVBIpf4KElLYySDV-do6Plq6-FiJnj4AjOyJoU4okTE+jnYAdERk+3jzaRlQOxIJOPOLlssATKvLG+7bJ63cZhY7RWI2I5XEikYH3dI+agmQrNfqDYajdQKBiCBgvWbwNoACk+uguhzsJ3UFBpkMu11IAEo3LhSToLvDhPwdgklmTOfwkdQGqiBkMRlAxtjcTNsDhUQAFQSWeC0FDqSyCFBgWTwFKsSU6jzWeCyKC6dQpFARKApYAlAAygkEAGsoGBhNacLJwQQkJZqSy8HhAX5yrLvb61joAOq4l11fj4f3qABk7iJ7jwAB8g8H8xTwuCzqDoWRefng5yfGGglng5JEjm85WQUcqSWodweBXW9X+jU6r2G+5GYEgA).

```
enum Animal {
  BIRD = 'bird',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

interface Smth<T extends Animal = Animal> {
  id: number;
  animalType: T;
  config: T extends 'bird' ? number : string; // if its bird - should be a number
}

const smth: Smth = {
  id: 1,
  animalType: Animal.BIRD,
  config: 1
};

const smth2: Smth = {
  id: 1,
  animalType: Animal.BIRD,
  config: 'x' // should be error
};

if (smth.animalType === Animal.BIRD) {
 smth.config = 1;
 smth.config = 'x'; // should be error
}

// Posible solution, but is it the only one? Look ugly
type Base = {
    id: number
}

type SmthWorking = Base &
  (
    | {
        animalType: Animal.BIRD;
        config: number;
      }
    | {
        animalType: Animal.DOG;
        config: string;
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably pass Smith a generic type; you can't infer the type from the setting `animalType` alone.

```
const smth2: Smth<Animal.BIRD> = {
  id: 1,
  animalType: Animal.BIRD,
  config: 'x' // ⚠️ gives you an error, no error for number
};
```

Comment: Is there a way for ts to pick it up from instance? I don't see a reason to pass this value as it exist on instance

Comment: @ZiiMakc, I'm not a typescript specialist, but you appear to be combining value and type in some way, thinking about types separately and with one-directional flow in mind. It seems more logical to me to type smth2 and infer animalType from that.